# What is the time complexity of this solution for the longest common prefix string among an array of strings?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, big-o

This is the problem statement -

Write a function to find the longest common prefix string amongst an array of strings.

I'm not sure on the time complexity on my solution below. I'm guessing it's ***O(nmnlogn)***. nlogn for the sort, and n*m for iterating through the array, and making m comparisons on the strings.

```
string longestCommonPrefix(vector<string>& strs) {
    if(strs.size() == 0) return "";

    sort(strs.begin(), strs.end());

    string prefix = strs[0];
    int length = prefix.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < strs.size(); ++i) {
        if (prefix == strs[i].substr(0, length)) continue;
        if (prefix != strs[i].substr(0, length)) {
            prefix = prefix.substr(0, --length);
            length = prefix.length();
            i = 0;
        }
        if (prefix == "") break;
    }

    return prefix;
}
```

Comment: You could simplify to n^2 * mlogn and the n^2 should dominate so I'd call it n^2 but depending on what you are trying to do the mlogn could be meaningful.

Comment: @mba12 ? I guess that might make some sense if there was **+** instead of **\***, but it's still fishy.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that everything after the sort is O(nm), then it would be O(nlogn + nm) (since you are doing the sort just once), which might be able to be simplified further based on the relationship between m and logn.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I'll answer since no one has answered correctly.
Your solution uses a sort, which is O(nlogn), and the loop traverses the entire list, albeit in a confusing manner (why set i=0 when finding that the prefix doesn't fit as a whole? every previous word has already been confirmed to has the entire prefix up to this point, so there is no need to re-check them after reducing the size of the prefix), with each iteration doing substring of length m (where m is the minimum length string in "strs[]"), so with substring being linear time complexity, your solution is O(nlogn + nm)<s>, which simplifies to O(nlogn),</s> which is not good.

You can easily improve upon your solution. 
(Hint) 
Question: why are you sorting the strs[]? 
Answer: to find the minimum string, which you then compare to every other string.
So if you only need the minimum string, this can be done in linear time (O(n)), sorting is unnecessary. This would reduce your algorithms time complexity from O(nlogn + nm) to O(n + nm) --> O(nm), with O(1) space complexity.

edit: @templatetypedef left a comment, correctly indicating that O(nlogn+nm) does not simplify to O(nlogn). This was an oversight of mine, as it wasn't the root of my answer, so I didn't think much into it when writing the post. I've corrected the post to better serve people learning big-O in the future

Comment: I like your algorithm more than the one posted by the OP, but I don’t believe your time analysis is correct. You can’t simplify O(n log n) to O(n log n), since the length of the longest string might be vastly greater than log n. Similarly, the sorting cost isn’t O(n log n) because you have to factor in the cost of comparing strings in the sort. Also, the cost of the inner loop is greater than expected because of the quadratic worst-case behavior of when mismatches are found.

Answer (score 0):

When you’re working with algorithms on strings, there are (usually) two separate quantities that we care about. First, there’s the number of strings, which we’ll denote n. Then, there’s the length of the strings. Let’s have the longest string’s length be m.

The reason this comes up is that we have to remember that m term throughout the algorithm. For example, the cost of the sort is *not* O(n log n), but rather O(mn log n), because while there are O(n log n) comparisons made, each comparison between strings might require scanning all the characters of those strings and thus we need to multiply in a factor of m to account for the comparisons.

The next part of your algorithm scans across the strings from left to right, comparing the longest viable prefix match found so far against each string until a match is detected. The cost of extracting the substring in this step is O(m), since we might need to grab a full substring. However, in the event that a mismatch is found, we’ll grab a shorter substring and try this again. In the worst case, we’ll first try a prefix of length m, then m-1, then m-2, etc, and that means we may have to do

> m + (m-1) + (m-2) + ... + 1 = Θ(m<sup>2</sup>)

work. Though, if that happens, we’d then do less work on all future strings because the prefix length would be shorter. The worst case here, I think, is one where we have n-1 copies of the same string of length m followed by one last string also of length m that has only the empty string as a prefix. In that case, we’d do Θ(m) work for all the first n-1 strings plus Θ(m<sup>2</sup>) work for the last, for a net total of O(mn + m<sup>2</sup>) work in the worst case.

Overall, that gives you a time complexity of O(mn log n + m<sup>2</sup>), which isn’t great.

There are faster alternatives you could consider here. For example, imagine throwing all the strings into a trie data structure. If you did this, their longest common prefix would be found by walking the trie until you found a branching node. Building the trie takes time O(mn), since you need to read each character of the input strings, for a net runtime of O(mn). This could be improved even more by realizing that you don’t actually need to store the whole trie - as soon as you find a branching node, you can discard everything else. You could simulate this by just tracking the longest match found so far, at each step comparing what you have against that matched string and truncating it if a mismatch is found. In fact, doing that starting with the shortest string first will take time O(nl), where l is the length of the shortest string, which is about as good as things can get here!

Hope this helps!